# linear objective function with linear constraints and one quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, constraints, non-convex-optimization, quantile-function

I have an optimization problem in which the objective function and most constraints are linear, but I  have one constraint is quadratic. I know my problem can not be reformulated as a convex , but if you have some advice on how to approach it in MATLAB ?

my problem as follows,
$$\begin{array}{cl}
\underset{w_{1},...,w_{6}}{ \min}&   \sum_{t=1}^n  ( - \mu_{t}(w)-u_t) \\s.t \sqrt{c_{1}^2+c_2^2} \geq u_{t} \\ c_{1}=h_{1t}(w) \\ c_{2}=h_{2t}(w)\\ w_1+...+w_6=1
\end{array} $$

please note, $ \mu_{t}(w) = a*w_1+...+a6*w_6 $ is a linear function. Also, $h_1t(w)= (b_1*w_1+...+b_6*w6 + d_1*w1+...+d_6*w_6)$ and $h_2t(w)= (f_1*w_1+...+f_6*w6 + g_1*w1+...+g_6*w_6)$. Finally, $a_1,...,a_6 , b_1,...,b_6 ,d_1,...,d_6 ,f_1,...,f_6$ and $g_1,...,g_6$ are constants.

EDIT: I add and remove some parts of my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Approach what? You have the model in standard form $\min c^T x, Ax\leq b$ ready to send to a LP solver, such as linprog in MATLAB.

Comment: but this is non convex function

Comment: my optimization variables are $w_1,...,w_6$ . $ h_{1t}(w)$ and  $h_{2t}(w)$  are both linear functions.
to my understanding: minimizing $ - \sqrt{h_{1t}(w) ^2 + h_{2t}(w)^2} $   same as minimizing - Norm which means  it is maximizing $\sqrt{h_{1t}(w) ^2 + h_{2t}(w)^2}$  and in this case my constraint will be $\sqrt{c_{1} ^2 + c_{2}^2} \geq u $   , if it is minimizing  without the negative sign then my constraint will be $\sqrt{c_{1} ^2 + c_{2}^2} \leq u $  which means it is second order cone. I hope I explained what was not unclear to you

Comment: You are writing down two problems, one which is non-convex (maximization of norm is non-convex, and so is norm-larger-than) , and then an LP which is claimed to be some kind of equivalent reformulation according to some reference. What is the problem then, just solve the LP?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I edited my optimization problem, can you please check that.

Comment: Not convex as you are maximizing a norm. You can still try to solve it though. Square the norm-constraint and you have a nonconvex quadratically constrained problem in 6 variables which should be solvable using a global solver. Very easy to test in YALMIP for instance https://yalmip.github.io/tutorial/globaloptimization/

Comment: so, if my problem is max   ( a1* w1 +...+a6w6 - c sqrt( h1(w) ^2+ h2(w)^2 )  )  does this mean it is convex function since I am maximizing the - norm ?

Comment: Maximizing a negated convex function is same as maximizing a concave and/or  minimizing a convex and thus tractable.  What you write now is simply minimizing a 2-norm (plus some linear), which is convex and SOCP-representable.

Comment: can you please check my other question which is related to your last answer. it's titled maximizing the negative norm is it convex problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After eliminating one variable using your equality constraint, you are left with minimizing a linear objective function over the exterior of an ellipsoid. In general this will have no solution (you can make the objective function arbitrarily negative, while keeping $c_1^2 +c_2^2$ large enough to satisfy the inequality constraint, if you walk far enough in the direction of the negative objective gradient).

But in any case, in general when faced with a nonlinear optimization problem, you have several options:

1. Invoke Matlab's built-in black-box solvers for nonlinear problems; for instance `fmincon` implements an interior-point solver.
2. Try to use insights about the problem to simplify it yourself. For instance you can split your problem up into a regular linear program (in the case where the inequality constraint is inactive) and minimization of a linear function on a quadric surface (in the case where it's active). You can then apply some changes of variable to turn the quadric into a sphere or cylinder, etc.

Comment: thank you, can you please explain more about the second option, I am not quite sure I have understand it fully